# 10.13.4 = 1 fewer monitors on my MacBook Pro mid 2012 (non-Retina)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, thunderbolt, dvi

I have a 2012 MBP non-retina.  I've been running 2 old CRT's along with the laptops monitor.  One CRT is connected through a Thunderbolt converter, and the other through a DVI/USB converter.  When my system automatically updated to 10.13.4 today, I soon learned that: 10.13.4 does not support the USB converter... which I guess Apple considers an 'enhancement'?

Just looking for some clever ideas as to how I might regain my expansive desktop, without 'having' to Time Machine back to 10.13.3.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the manufacturer of the USB to DVI converter.  But, just going off the info in the question - I would say you may have to find another one.

Comment: The USB converter is a DisplayLink Adaptor.  It seemed from what I've found thus far that 10.13.4 does not support USB as a means of connecting another display?  Maybe not...

Comment: Klanomath - I do appreciate the GitHub citation.  It certainly seems a clever idea, but I've avoided Terminal since it's inception, as I seem to have an uncanny predilection for issues that techies often respond to by noting: 'i've never heard of ____ before'.

Comment: DisplayLink published a new beta driver 4.3b2 (clone mode only!): http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=1131 According to comments in their support forum still buggy/impossible to use.

Comment: Thanks again.  My impatience (and clients), led me to the nuclear option of a Time Machine restore.  Once complete the screen turned to a circle with a line through it.  After Internet Recovery, Disk Utility indicates my 1 TB Crucial SSD is fine, but, the "diskOs2" thereunder is not mounted, and will not mount.  The Partition Type is a very lengthy string of letters/numbers.  Other than Capacity, everything is blank.  No Verify or Repair option.  Any ideas?  Maybe do another Time Machine restore?

Comment: @TimHim Please add a new question (instead of asking an almost unrelated question in a comment), Add some screenshots (e.g. `gpt -r show disk0`/`diskutil list` output)

Comment: Thanks klanomath.  It did occur to me that my question belonged elsewhere.  Again, the accelerating rush I'm in (as a 'quick/easy' Time Machine restore of an Outlook Identity turned into a full 4-day reset that I am praying is going to continue to work... at least until I get my taxes done and time-sensitive client services up-to-date), led me to just blast-out the question without spending the requisite time to determine where it should be posted.  Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to a bug in the DisplayLink driver used by your converter.

DisplayLink are aware of the problem,. They have issued a beta of a new driver that actually doesn't fix the problem. You can view their note on the problem at http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/macos It doesn't support multiple screens on multiple displays.

They have a mailing list supposedly for updates but have failed to notify the mailing list of the last two updates so I wouldn't bother.

I also wouldn't blame Apple. Both Apple and a number of 10.13.4 beta users (including myself) advised DisplayLink of the problem quite some time ago.

Update: DisplayLink have issued a second 4.3 beta that doesn't fix the problem. They have also removed the 4.1 version from their site. (4.2 has never been seen.)

(I will update this answer when DisplayLink put out a working driver.)

Comment: Thanks Tony.  I did sign up for the mail list, so I certainly appreciate your offering to further update me when/if a new driver is made available.  Sounds as though this is 'fixable' with a software update?

Comment: No worries, Tim. You don't know how angry DisplayLink has made me over this.

Comment: Hi Tony et. al.,

Comment: Just FYI: somehow the auto-update in preferences turned-on, and I awoke to a 'new' computer completing it's upgrade!!!! I thought for sure, I was gonna spend another day going back to 10.13.3 to keep that precious 3rd monitor... and once the machine completed booting - the 3rd (& favorite ViewSonic 21" CRT that's 20+ years old and looks better than any Retina I ever saw), sprung to life like nothing ever happened!!! Yeeee Haaaa! I never saw any updates that might have let me know sooner so I thought I should spread the word.